# How much does Lemony Snicket know while telling "A Series of Unfortunate Events"?

Tags: a-series-of-unfortunate-events

As I was watching *A Series of Unfortunate Events* on Netflix again, I wondered about how much Lemony Snicket is aware of future events while telling the individual stories.

Lemony breaks the fourth wall and tells the story of the Baudelaire in the past. But is the past like "Book 1 happens and Lemony tells us what's going on, then book 2 happens, etc."?
Or is it more like "All 13 Books happened and years later Lemony tells us the story"?

Answer (score 1):

He is telling the story about 12+ years after the events of Hotel Denouement. He keeps telling the story until he meets Beatrice Baudelaire II (played by [Angelina Capozzoli](https://snicket.fandom.com/wiki/Angelina_Capozzoli) who was about 13 or 14 in 2019 when Season 3 was released).

He knows most of the events (both from his research and his close connection to many of the characters) up to the events of Hotel Denouement. He doesn't seem to know about the Baudelaires getting to the island or what happened in the intervening 12+ years (neither do we--all we know is that after one year on the island, the Baudelaires leave the island and Beatrice II eventually meets up with him 12+ years later).